# Yet another request entity too large issue, Apache

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php.ini

When I try to upload any kind of file to my server/website I get an Request Entity Too Large error. (Trying to upload a 1.73mb picture produces a 413 error while a 25.6kb picture does not)

I tried various "fixes" but they didn't work for me, it might be something with the ssl but I am not sure.

The website uses SSL/https for very page.
What is wrong with this machine?

My setup is: Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 7.0, Apache 2.4.18, 2GBs of ram, 500 gbs of disk space

My Apache uses "Security" and all these modules:

```
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
```

The website config:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@physiosquantum.com
    ServerName physiosquantum.com
    ServerAlias www.physiosquantum.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/peacefulnukes

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]    

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@physiosquantum.com
        ServerName physiosquantum.com
        ServerAlias www.physiosquantum.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/peacefulnukes

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder on
        SSLCipherSuite "ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS"
        SSLCompression Off
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/peacefulnukes.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/peacefulnukes.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>

        <Directory />           
            AllowOverride All
            LimitRequestBody 512000
            Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/gitlab>
            Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
        </IfModule>

        ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
        ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
        ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
        ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
        ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Apache2 conf:

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
#Deny all config files even if they are samples/examples
<FilesMatch "config\.php">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "config\.inc\.php">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "config\.sample\.php">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "config\.sample\.inc\.php">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "wp-config\.php">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "config\.sample\.inc\.php">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
# Disable SSLv3
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
# MySQL auth (libapache2-mod-auth-apache2).
# Global config of MySQL server address, username, password.

ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod

AddType image/x-icon .ico
<Files favicon.ico>
    ErrorDocument 404 /icons/favicon.ico
</Files>

#Attempt to fix the issue
LimitRequestBody 104860000
LimitRequestFieldSize 104860000
```

My PHP.ini (Tried to revert back to the default (since I had hardened it before) but it didn't fixed the problem):

```
(Can't put all of it here but here is the important stuff)
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 8M
max_file_uploads = 20
memory_limit = 128M
```

Thank you for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `LimitRequestBody 512000` which [limit the number of bytes that are allowed in a request body](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) to 500kB.

Comment: Ding ding ding! We have a winner.

Comment: This didn't fixed it, plus "This directive specifies the number of bytes from 0 (meaning unlimited) to 2147483647 (2GB) that are allowed in a request body" I removed the LimitRequestFieldSize and edited the LimitRequestBody to 0 (unlimited) also tried with 512000

Comment: These are two others variables that could affect, but reading the error message that you got I don't think they are the problem, still just in case:   `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time`. I know that this is basic but some time we miss basic things... did you restart apache? Did you change the values of some conf variable from your code?

Comment: Tried "max_execution_time = 999" with "max_input_time = -1" didn't work. Yes I restarted apache2 and I edited php.ini in "/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini" for the max_execution stuff and for  the limitrequestbody I edited the "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf". PHP is default (since I purged it and reinstalled it) and for apache I only edited apache.conf and added sites. One thing that is wierd is that I never had problems with 413 errors on ubuntu 14.04 maybe should I try to install php5 and purge php7 to test?

Comment: Tried to run php5.6 and it still gave me the error (I am not removing limitrequestbody and I also added the max_file_size variables to that php version)

Comment: I suggest that you start clean in a virtual machine or container and test a simple upload php script available on Internet. Then from there, start adding  peace after peace the configurations that is giving you problems.

Comment: Fixed it, I searched for "LimitRequestBody" in all config files and I found where the problem was